# Python gives "ordinal not in range" error from __str__ but not from print

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

I have an object that reads in some data from a JSON file. Some of the JSON data is strings with Latin 1 characters, for example:

```
"name" : "frisée"
```

I stringify this object as a table containing some of the strings read out of the JSON object. If I write this:

```
def __str__(self): # Never mind the details, what matters is that I use __str__
    ts = [p + (count,) for p, count in self.counts.items()]
    ts.sort(key=lambda x:(x[2], x[0], x[1]))
    return "\n".join(["%s\t%s\t%s" % (t[0], t[1], t[2]) for t in ts])
```

And then try to run `print MyObject()` I get the error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 9112: ordinal not in range(128)
```

However, if I write this:

```
def to_string(self):
    ts = [p + (count,) for p, count in self.counts.items()]
    ts.sort(key=lambda x:(x[2], x[0], x[1]))
    return "\n".join(["%s\t%s\t%s" % (t[0], t[1], t[2]) for t in ts])
```

and then run `print MyObject().to_string()` everything works. The "é" character is printed correctly.

Why does `__str__` have different behavior than `to_string`? What can I do to make the `__str__` version print correctly?

I've tried various iterations of `encode` to no avail.

Comment: You have *Latin-1* data, not *high ASCII*. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `__str__` is returning a *`unicode`* type value; JSON strings are always Unicode. However, the [`__str__` result must *always* return a *bytestring*, so type `str`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__). If you don't, Python calls `str()` on the result for you, which means it'll implicitly encode any Unicode using the default ASCII codec.

Explicitly encode your result:

```
def __str__(self):
    ts = [p + (count,) for p, count in self.counts.items()]
    ts.sort(key=lambda x:(x[2], x[0], x[1]))
    return u'\n'.join([u'\t'.join(t[:2]) for t in ts]).encode('utf8')
```

or use a [`__unicode__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__unicode__) instead. This will not be called by `print` though; you'd have to do so explicitly with `print unicode(MyObject())`.

`print` knows how to encode `unicode` strings correctly, provided your terminal is configured properly. It'll use `sys.stdout.encoding` to explicitly encode your Unicode data. This is why `MyObject().to_string()` works.